# StringBuffer indexOf a parenthesis then insert returns an infinite loop

Tags: java

```
public static String spaceParen( String text){

    if( ( text.length() == 0 ) ||  (text == null ) ) {
        return "";
    }

    StringBuffer spacedString = new StringBuffer( text );

    int index1 = 0;

    // finds the index of ( , then inserts a space after and before it
    // Ex: (test -> ( test or ( test -> (  test
    index1 = spacedString.indexOf("(");
    while(index1 > -1){
        System.out.println("index1 of ( = " + index1);
        spacedString.insert(index1," ( ");

        index1 = spacedString.indexOf("(", index1+2);
    }
    // finds the index of ), then inserts a space after and before it
    // Ex: test) ->  test ) or  test )->  test  )
    index1 = spacedString.indexOf(")");
    while(index1 > -1){
        System.out.println("index1 of ) = " + index1);
        spacedString.insert(index1, " ) ");

        index1 = spacedString.indexOf(")", index1+2);
    }


    return spacedString.toString();
}
```

This is the Output I'm getting:

```
index1 of ( = 69
index1 of ( = 72
index1 of ( = 75
index1 of ( = 78
index1 of ( = 81
index1 of ( = 84
index1 of ( = 87
index1 of ( = 90
index1 of ( = 93
index1 of ( = 96
index1 of ( = 99
index1 of ( = 102
index1 of ( = 105
index1 of ( = 108
index1 of ( = 111
index1 of ( = 114
index1 of ( = 117
index1 of ( = 120
index1 of ( = 123
index1 of ( = 126
index1 of ( = 129
index1 of ( = 132
index1 of ( = 135
index1 of ( = 138
index1 of ( = 141
index1 of ( = 144
index1 of ( = 147
index1 of ( = 150
```

The list goes on and on, in a loop. I tried it with double slash \( and \) and it just ignores the parenthesis. I used StringBuffer before but this never happened. I don't know why is it happening and how to fix it.

Comment: An alternative method would be String.replaceAll("([()])"," $1 ")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider string `(abc)(xyz)`

first it finds index `(` at index `0` and replaces with `(`
Now

spacedString = `( (abc)(xyz)`
index1 = 3

#### Notice previous `(` not removed and new one added at front.

Next iteration

spacedString = `(  ( (abc)(xyz)`
index1 = 6

Next iteration

spacedString = `(  (  ( (abc)(xyz)`
index1 = 9
.
.
So on till infinity.

## HOW TO FIX :

Remove old parenthesis. Simplest way is to replace

```
String spacedString;
spacedString = text.replaceAll("(", " ( ");
spacedString = spacedString.replaceAll(")", " ) ");
```

Comment: Yes, this was the problem that was happening. Should have used replaceAll() than what ever I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

First, this

```
if( ( text.length() == 0 ) ||  (text == null ) ) {
    return "";
}
```

will NPE on `null` - test them reversed,

```
if( (text == null ) || ( text.length() == 0 ) ) {
    return "";
}
```

correct. Because you add a " ( " and then search for the next paren (which you just moved three spaces right). I believe I would use replace and something like,

```
String text = "(abc) (def)";
StringBuffer spacedString = new StringBuffer( 
    text.replace("(", " ( ").replace(")", " ) ")
);
System.out.println(spacedString);
```

Output is

```
 ( abc )   ( def )
```